# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED SSL error when trying to connect to a database in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use MongoDB with Python, but every time I try to access/connect to my database or do some action, it doesn't work, and an error is displayed in the terminal.

My code is as follows:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb+srv://******:<**************>@cluster0.dr6egzq.mongodb.net/')

mydb = myclient['mydatabase']
mycol = mydb["customers"]

mydict = { "name": "John", "address": "Highway 37" }

x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)

print(x)
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\testingMongo.py", line 11, in <module>
    x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 628, in insert_one
    self._insert_one(
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 569, in _insert_one      
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1475, in _retryable_write
    with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1757, in _tmp_session  
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1740, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1685, in __start_session
    self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 538, in _check_implicit_session_support
    self._check_session_support()
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 554, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
    File "C:\Users\black\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 238, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 
ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-01.dr6egzq.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007),
ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-02.dr6egzq.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007),
ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-00.dr6egzq.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007), 
Timeout: 30s, 
Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6467ddd302fb8613579250bb, 
topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, 
servers: [
<ServerDescription ('ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-00.dr6egzq.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-00.dr6egzq.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)')>, 
<ServerDescription ('ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-01.dr6egzq.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-01.dr6egzq.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)')>, 
<ServerDescription ('ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-02.dr6egzq.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-yeuyapn-shard-00-02.dr6egzq.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)')>
]>
```

Comment: Your connection string is to `localhost`, but the error message is from `...mongodb.net`.  Are you connecting to more than one MongoDB server?

Comment: It says "certificate has expired". What is not clear with this message?

Comment: In this code, you don't use any certificate.

Comment: Ok but how I do then ? I tried a lot of things always the same message even if I put SSL_NO_CERTIFICATE thing it doesn't work !

Comment: what do you mean by more than one MongoDB server ? I don't think so. mongodb://localhost:27017/ Is not what I putted I replaced it by my account and password in my script

Comment: What do you mean by "replaced"? The connection string has a strict format see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: I mean I used my nickname and my password but that's a string format this example above "localhost" is just a thing I putted right here to not show my mongo password and name but all the example to insert the user was on W3C and when I tried to insert one the certificate error was displayed.

Comment: Nobody ask you to disclose your username or password. But should provide us your connection string (replace your password by `********`), otherwise nobody would be able to provide any help. Don't be concerned about the server name - you published it already by the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it work I needed ISRG Root X1,ISRG Root X2 and Let's Encrypt R3 and needed to remove the '< >' around the password in the connection string

https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

That's the .der for the 1st category to download

It was explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXvK-HZMG0A

Answer (score 1):

Try certifi package is a Python library that provides a set of root certificates for verifying the authenticity of SSL/TLS connection.

`import certifi`